Maximum number of simultaneous Bluetooth devices supported on Apple TV 4K?
My friend complains that her Apple TV 4K only supports two Bluetooth commercials at a time. She is trying to use more as part of using a bicycle training app with multiple pieces of apparatus.
Two seems like a low number to me given that Apple TV 4K is akin to a full-fledged computer like iPad and iPhone.
The specs on Apple web site says the Apple TV 4K uses Bluetooth 5.0 wireless technology.
Is there a known limit on the number of Bluetooth devices that can communicate at the same time with Apple TV 4K?
I suppose the remote control would take one connection.

I think it is 2 Bluetooth connections.
However, I use Apple TV to connect to Zwift, ROUVY, FulGaz and TrainingPeaks virtual using a smart trainer with no issues.
If you have a smart trainer (I use Tacx) then it does cadence, power and the trainer on a single Bluetooth connection as a trainer only has a single Bluetooth device, the second channel I use for a heart rate monitor. If your are an elite cyclist on the platforms you have to use a second power meter but this has to connect to a cycling headunit not Apple TV. I also use headwinds for fans but via mobile to control.
Is your friend trying to connect other devices?
Hope that helps. Happy cycling
Kevin
